# REST API style for tree structure

Tags: javascript, rest, web

I have items in tree structure.  Each `Item` has `Id` and `ParentId`.

To get `Item` by `Id` I use `items/:id`

What is the best way to create endpoint for `GetItemsByParentId(parentId)` method?

Comment: `/parent/{id}/items`?

Comment: if you get the item as json when you get items/:id, then in that json you could also have child list as an integer array like this: {children: 2,3,4,5}. same principle would go for xml.

Comment: `/items/{id}//children`. You would rather ask a person "Who are your children" than "Who has you as parent", wouldn't you?

Comment: @zeroflagL I think you should post your suggestion as an answer, it's really good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would rather ask a person "Who are your children" than "Who has you as parent", wouldn't you? That said I suggest to use `/items/{id}/children`.

The response you get from the server usually contains the appropriate link in that case:

```
{
  links: {
    self: "http://foo/items/2",
    children: "http://foo/items/2/children"
  },
  ...
}
```

Your API could also support embedding children on demand. Something like `http://foo/items/2?embedChildren` or a different media type in the `Accept` header could then return:

```
{
  links: {
    self: "http://foo/items/2",
    children: "http://foo/items/2/children"
  }
  children: [
   ...
  ],
  ... 
}
```

Including the `children` link in that case too is a good idea. That way you can still add children posting to that URL.